# how would I fix my code inorder to create a file of words in this format(see body)?

Tags: python, python-requests, spyder

see if the word can be read backwards and is also a word in the file. If the word is, save the word in the list. After you go through each of the words, sort the list, print out/write the word paired with its read-backwards word to a new file.

[the format that should be the final outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZEi5.png)

this is my code so far and i was wondering if anyone could help me?

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\RandomWords.txt')
words = f.readlines() #creats list and gets rid of whitespace
for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].strip()

f.close()

f2 = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\finaloutput.txt', 'w')

for j in words:
    temp = j.lower()[::-1] #reads backwards
    if j.capitalize() in words:
        f2.write('{}--{}\n'.format(words[i], temp))
f2.close()
```

ok so this is my updated code and I need help sorting it and getting rid of repeated words in the new written file named Target.txt.

[This is part of the file Target.txt and there are repeat words father down but I cant fit it in the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CILD2.png)

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\RandomWords.txt')
words = f.readlines() #creats list and gets rid of whitespace

list1 = []

for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].strip()
    list1.append(words[i])

f.close()

f2 = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Target.txt', 'w')


for j in words:
    temp = j.lower()[::-1] #reads backwards
    if temp.capitalize() in list1:
        list1.remove(temp.capitalize())
        f2.write('{}--{}\n'.format(j, temp.capitalize()))
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was right you were just using the wrong variable when putting it back in the final words.

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\RandomWords.txt')
words = f.readlines() #creats list and gets rid of whitespace
for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].strip()

f.close()

f2 = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\OneDrive\\Documents\\finaloutput.txt', 'w')

for j in words:
    print('yes')
    temp = j.lower()[::-1] #reads backwards
    if temp.capitalize() in words:
        print('uwu')
        f2.write('{}--{}\n'.format(j, temp))
f2.close()
```

you also used j instead of temp in your if statement.
because you used `words[i]` when writing it to the file it would only write the last item in the random words file. and because you used the `j` variable instead of `temp` it wasn't flipped and therefore didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: do you think you could help me with my new questions?